# Keep containers in middle column centered when browser width changes

Tags: html, css

I have a fluid width layout. Left and right column have a fixed width and my center column changes its width in between max and min width specified as the browser width changes or screen resolution changes. It looks like image below:

[image]

As you can see, there are some small containers in middle column, they hold up several products etc.

The problem that I am experiencing is that when the width changes and middle column cannot accommodate 3 containers, 1 will fall below, as they are floated and then it looks like something below:

[image]

Now this space that comes in the right of containers looks ugly. What I want to do is to keep them centered if one falls below when width decreases then two should appear in the center of the middle column and when another one falls then 1 container left should also appear in the middle like below:

[image]

Can I do this with css only? or I need to introduce some scripting language for doing it dynamically?

This is the css for container, that I am using

```css
.prod-container{
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 290px;
    margin: 2px 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Example on http://www.myappontest.heliohost.org/index1.html

Comment: Can you please show us a full demo -- or at least provide a link to your site if it's live? It's hard to guess what `.prod-container` is or how other elements are styled. Pretty please with artificial sweetener on top?

Comment: @Abody97 you can find an example on http://www.myappontest.heliohost.org/index1.html

Comment: Try to use fixed width in .prod-container. Instead of that, use percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `float: left;` with `display: inline-block;` in `.prod-container`'s style and adding `text-align: center;` to  `#center-content-container`'s style will achieve the desired behavior.

Working version of your page: [little link](http://goo.gl/6VmXE). Here's the modified CSS file, too: [another little link](http://goo.gl/Wun5E).

Hope that helped you in any manner!

Comment: I tried using inline-block but forgot to use text-align: center for that. Its perfect, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I would put the center floating blocks inside a div with a max-width 100% (in the scope of the center column). Center that block with "margin-left: auto margin-right: auto". This will keep the floating blocks moving to the next line if there's not enough room, and the centering div will size with it's contents, allowing it to center within the center column.